# Javascript - Hide all elements that do not have the specified ID

Tags: javascript

Hey there StackOverflow Community!

I'm fairly new to Stack and coding in general so this code will probably have an obvious error that I can't figure out.

Basically, in the following code I want everything shown on screen that isn't the element with the id `settings` to be hidden.

```js
if ((!"#settings").style.display === "block") {
        $(!"#settings").hide();
    }
```

HTML:

```html
<body>
    <span id="mainBtnArea">
        <button id="settings-btn">Settings</button>
        <button id="stats-btn">Stats</button>
    </span>
    <div id="mainArea">
        <h1 id="clickHeader"></h1>
        <button id="main-btn">Click Me</button>
    </div>
    <div id="settings">
        <h1>this is the page I want to show</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="stats">
        <p id="stats-clicks" class="stats">Keys:</p>
        <p id="stats-keys" class="stats">Keys:</p>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].id != 'settings') {
        elements[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

You need to have a forloop!
Update: You have to add an element tag DIV in order for it to work. Please see above.

It works for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/bowtiekreative/j697okqd/1/

Comment: This didn't work unfortunately, I substituted in the ID I wanted to keep showing but everything on the page becomes not visible, including the element I want to show, If it helps, the element I want to show has the css of "display: none". I only want the 'settings" element to show after I press "settings-btn" in the span.

Comment: Please check the updated code. I don't think you did it correctly. So I updated it for you.

Comment: @Riftzy this should work - have you tried it? I even put a working example.

Comment: I changed it around a little bit so it also included the <h1> element but overall yes it worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Query selectors don't work quite like that - you can't negate a selector with a ! symbol.

You can, however, use the [visible selector](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and the  [not selector](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/). The following will hide every element that is a child of body ($("body.find"), is a div or span (div, span), is visible (:visible), and doesn't have the id 'settings' (:not('#settings'))

```
 $("body").find("div:not('#settings'), span").hide()
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I managed to get every visible element to disappear. However, the element(s) that I wanted to show on screen don't appear. :)

Comment: It is possible that the element with id "x" is contained within one of the elements that was hidden - in that case, the element with id x won't show up because the parent is hidden, and the DOM follows a hierarchy. Alternatively, maybe you have multiple elements with the id "x"? Ids should be unique. If you edit your post with your HTML it will be easier to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Alright I'll edit with the HTML. To add on, no it doesn't have a parent just the "body" tag and I always make sure to use different ID's when writing code

Comment: I think because the body is a visible element it's also being hidden - try something like this: $("body").find("div:not('#settings'), span").hide()

Comment: Hey there, this isn't working either. For some more context, feel free to read my comment on the other solution.